# MAMP (PRO) can not be installed yet Stop all servers but no server found

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I am getting below error message while installing MAMP on Mac. I've checked activity monitor for httpd and mysqld processes but no processes found and i've also used terminal to quit any active mysql process but nothing founf there too. Any suggestion how i can navigate the below error message.

Error Message
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwTLD.png

MAMP (PRO) can not be installed yet!
First, you have to
• stop all servers,
• deactivate the Dynamic DNS service,
• turn off server starts at system startup,
• and quit MAMP & MAMP PRO.

If you keep seeing this message please restart your Mac.

Many thanks.

Comment: Some here. I gave up.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem here, even completley restarting (as asked by Mamp) does not solve the problem. An additionnal info (I don't know if the original poster is in that same situation): I am in fact upgrading from MAMP Intel 6.3 to MAMP M1/ARM 6.6 (on a M1 Mac of course), might this be the problem ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, however, I wasn't using MAMPPro and there was no `mysqld_proxy.pid` file to be found.

What I had to do was rename my MAMP folder, launch the installer, and then change the name of the MAMP folder back. Then continue the installer and it updated and made a backup of the old MAMP install like it should.

Comment: Renaming the /Applications/MAMP folder to get the installer started and then changing the name back to continue the installation worked perfectly on my M2 Pro. The other solutions did not work for my setup.

Comment: This worked as described.

Comment: Life saver, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I faced up the same problem (upgrading to Mamp Pro 6.6 on a Mac M1), with not processes running.
As DavidH told, deleting file /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/tmp/mysqld_proxy.pid has worked for me and the installation has been completed successfully.

Answer (score 4):

other place to remove:
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid
/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/httpd.pid

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I had an error message "MAMP & MAMP PRO 6.6 can’t be installed on this computer." So, I was trying to solve it and only found this thread on Stakoverflow. A couple of hours later I realised I downloaded "MAMP & MAMP PRO 6.6 (M1)" package from here mamp.info/en/downloads although my Mac processor is Intel. So, I downloaded "MAMP & MAMP PRO 6.6 (Intel)" package and managed to install new MAMP with no problems.
Of course, it's not an answer for the question as this person here has problems with M1 Mac but hopefully my answer is helpful for someone who has the same problem as I had.

Comment: Your answer could be a lot better with more detail.

Comment: I had an error message yesterday "MAMP & MAMP PRO 6.6 can’t be installed on this computer." So, I was trying to solve it, find the answer and a couple of hours later I realised I downloaded "MAMP & MAMP PRO 6.6 (M1)" package from here https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/ although my Mac processor is Intel. So, I downloaded "MAMP & MAMP PRO 6.6 (Intel)" package and managed to install new MAMP with no problems.

Comment: If you add this information as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71207776/edit) to your answer, this may help future visitors. Comments have a tendency to get deleted

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  I took the following steps:

1. Make sure "mysqld_proxy" isn't running by quitting (not "Force quit") the process "mysqld_proxy" using "Activity Monitor.app"
2. remove "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/tmp/mysqld_proxy.pid"

I was then able to install successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem and as @Anastasiia says below, the issue was my processor. I hadn't paid much attention at the download to realize the processor mattered, and frankly I'd have expected a better error message since they obviously know they didn't find the processor they were looking for, so they could have informed me. Anyway, solved easily with the proper download package. I needed the one for the Intel processor, not M1.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such a problem, the solution is really simple, just download the version for intel and everything will work